# ObjectDisposed exception: What am I doing wrong in MVC 3 EF deep loading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to deep-load a EF object and keep it in cache for a certain period. In my case, I have an object (say User) and then an internal list of Books set as a virtual collection

```
public virtual ICollection<Books> ListOfBooks { get; set; }
```

Where there's a foreign key relation between Books and User (and it all works fine)

I'm trying to deep-load this in a static central class

```
public static List<User> LoadAllBooksAndUsers() {

  using (MyDB dc = new MyDB())
  {

      dc.Users.Include("ListOfBooks");
      List<User> a = dc.Users.Where(l => l.Status == 1).ToList();

      return a;             
   }
}
```

In my calling code, I have something like this:

```
var evx = DB.LoadAllBooksAndUsers();
var q = evx.Single(m=>m.name==name);
```

Examining evx in the debugger or q.ListOfBooks shows that the listOfBooks has an objects disposed exception and it is null.

And this is random - it seems to work once in a while and I don't know under what condition.

I'm clueless as to what's happening - my understanding is that using .Include() and then enumerating it will load all dependent foreign key objects, so why isn't the method deep-loading all books into the user? What am I missing?

(I'd like to deep-load this object and cache it for a while as the data in it is used frequently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `Include` wrong. You need to use it together with the query building not in itself:

```
List<User> a = dc.Users.Include("ListOfBooks")
                       .Where(l => l.Status == 1)                           
                       .ToList();
```

You can find more info [in this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) about eager loading.

Comment: This is right. Also, I would like to suggest not returning the list and then filtering in memory but to have a new method that does the whole thing with a single sql query.

Comment: Thanks! That does just what I wanted it to do!! Just letting you know: It seems I can only do  .Include().Where() but not .Where().Include().